# Custom admin module edit option display's form in the place of tabs. and form place is empty, Why this?

Tags: magento-1.8, forms, module, tabs, edit-order

I am developing custom admin module. everything working fine but when I click on grid to edit the value, the form and information is displaying on left side on the tabs place, 
[image]

Why it is happening following is the code.

```
Npm/Manoreport/Block/Donationreport
<?php
class Npm_Manoreport_Block_Donationreport extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getDonationreport()
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('donationreport')) {
            $this->setData('commission', Mage::registry('commission'));
        }
        return $this->getData('donationreport');

    }
}



Npm/Manoreport/Block/Adminhtml/Donationreport
<?php
class Npm_Manoreport_Block_Adminhtml_Donationreport extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_removeButton('add');
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_donationreport';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'manoreport';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('manoreport')->__('Report');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('manoreport')->__('Add Item');
    }
}


    Npm/Manoreport/Block/Adminhtml/Donationreport/Edit
    <?php
    class Npm_Manoreport_Block_Adminhtml_Donationreport_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();

            $this->_objectId = 'id';
            $this->_blockGroup = 'manoreport';
            $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_donationreport';

            $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('manoreport')->__('Save Item'));
            $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('manoreport')->__('Delete Item'));

            $this->_addButton('saveandcontinue', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Save And Continue Edit'),
                'onclick'   => 'saveAndContinueEdit()',
                'class'     => 'save',
            ), -100);

            $this->_formScripts[] = "
                function toggleEditor() {
                    if (tinyMCE.getInstanceById('donationreport_content') == null) {
                        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'donationreport_content');
                    } else {
                        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'donationreport_content');
                    }
                }

                function saveAndContinueEdit(){
                    editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
                }
            ";
        }

        public function getHeaderText()
        {
            if(Mage::registry('donationreport_data') && Mage::registry('donationreport_data')->getId()) {
                return Mage::helper('manoreport')->__("Edit Item '%s'", $this->htmlEscape(Mage::registry('donationreport_data')->getTitle()));
            } else {
                return Mage::helper('manoreport')->__('Add Item');
            }
        }
    }

    Npm/Manoreport/Block/Adminhtml/Donationreport/Edit/Tabs
    <?php
    class Npm_Manoreport_Block_Adminhtml_Donationreport_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->setId('donationreport_tabs');
            $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
            $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('manoreport')->__('Donation Information'));
        }

        protected function _beforeToHtml()
        {
            $this->addTab('form_section', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('manoreport')->__('Donation'),
                'title'     => Mage::helper('manoreport')->__('Donation'),
                'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('manoreport/adminhtml_donationreport_edit_tab_form')->toHtml(),
            ));

            return parent::_beforeToHtml();
        }
    }

    Npm/Manoreport/Block/Adminhtml/Donationreport/Edit/Form
    <?php
    class Npm_Manoreport_Block_Adminhtml_Donationreport_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
    {
        protected function _prepareForm()
        {
            $form = new Varien_Data_Form(
                array(
                    'id' => 'edit_form',
                    'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
                    'method' => 'post',
                    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
                    )
            );
            $form->setUseContainer(true);
            $this->setForm($form);
            return parent::_prepareForm();
        }
    }

<?php
class Npm_Manoreport_Block_Adminhtml_Donationreport_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('donationreport_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('manoreport')->__('Fees Information')));

        $fieldset->addField('order_id', 'text', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('manoreport')->__('Order Id'),
            'readonly' => true,
            'disabled' => true,
            'name'      => 'order_id',
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('created_at', 'text', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('manoreport')->__('Date'),
            'readonly' => true,
            'disabled' => true,
            'name'      => 'created_at',
            ));
        $fieldset->addField('foundation_fees', 'text', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('manoreport')->__('Foundation Fees'),
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'foundation_fees',
        ));

        if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getdonationreportData()) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getdonationreportData());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setdonationreportData(null);
        } elseif (Mage::registry('donationreport_data')) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::registry('donationreport_data')->getData());
        }
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```